# What’s the ratio between the sums of areas of these circles and triangles?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Start with a unit circle. First inscribe it with an equilateral triangle, then  inscribe the equilateral triangle with a smaller circle, repeat the $2$ steps $99$ times, we end up with $101$ circles and $100$ triangles. What’s the ratio between the sums of areas of these circles and triangles?

With 30$^o$ right triangle, I can see the side of the first triangle is $\sqrt{3}$, the radius  of the second circle is 1/2 of the very first one, then?

[image]

Comment: Your description is ambiguous. You should provide a figure...

Comment: Thanks! Figure added.

Comment: Thanks for the figure. I am tempted to answer that this ratio is the same as doing it at the initial step with one triangle and the unit disk... but maybe I have still not understood what areas you consider. If you call $C_n$ and $T_n$ the $n$th circle and triangle areas, do you mean the ratio sum of all $T_n$ over sum of all $C_n$ ?

Comment: yes, the last shape is a circle.

Comment: Please show the attempts that you have done so far.

Comment: Remember to show your work on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the similarity, the ratios between the shapes stays the same.  If the first triangle has side $\sqrt 3$ and the second circle has radius $\frac 12$, the second triangle has side $\frac 12 \sqrt 3$ and the third circle has radius $\frac 14$.  The areas of either the circles or triangles form a geometric series with ratio $\frac 14$ as the areas scale as the square of the side.

Comment: I think you made an error since you have 101 circles and only 100 triangles.

Comment: @Moti:  I claimed a geometric series without stating how many terms there are.

Comment: Since the asking included a response that "yes, the last shape is a circle."  In you answer You should have pointed the error by the asking - at least in my opinion. The 101's circle should be discarded from the picture. I would also expect to see $\pi$ somewhere in the ratio between circle and triangle areas.